# Proving Undecidability of this Language

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, halting-problem

Consider the language
$$L = \{\langle M \rangle \mid  \text{$\exists$ an input $x$, where $|x|<i$, such that $M$ halts on $x$, but it takes at least $j$ steps} \}$$ where $i$ and $j$ are fixed non-zero natural number for L

I am trying to prove that $L$ is **undecidable**.

My thought is that reduce the **Universal Language** to $L$. That is, I should describe an algorithm that transforms an input $\langle M,w \rangle$ into an output $\langle M' \rangle$ the code for another TM, then assume that there is a TM $M_1$ that can decide $L$, which means $M_1$ accepts $\langle M' \rangle$ iff $L(M') = L$. Then I design a TM $M_2$ such that it first reads $\langle M,w \rangle$ and transforms it into $\langle M' \rangle$ according to the algorithm, and then it operates on $M_1$. I am stuck on how to design the algorithm or the $M'$ so that I can create a contradiction such as universal language is recursive.

Am I on the correct track?

Comment: What's $i$? What's $j$?

Comment: $i$ and $j$ are just fixed non-zero natural number for L, for example, $i$ can be 5, and $j$ can be 2022. I make $i$ and $j$ more general because I don't think different numbers of $i$ and $j$ will affect the proof, such as $|x|<i$ tells us that the potential input strings for $M$ are finite no matter what $i$ is.

Comment: What do you mean by "$M$ halts on $x$ in at least $j$ steps"? Do you mean "$M$ halts on $x$, but it takes $M$ at least $j$ steps"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $i$ and $j$ as two positive integers, as per your comment.

Consider the language $H$ containing all pairs $\langle T, y\rangle$ where $T$ is (encoding of) a Turing machine, $y \in \Sigma^*$, and $T$ halts when its input is $y$.

Notice that, given $\langle T, y\rangle$, you can compute (the description of) a Turing machine $M^{(j)}_{T, y}$ that, "waits" for $j$ steps, clears its tape, writes $y$, resets its head on the first position of $y$ (if any), and finally simulates $T$. I claim that $\langle T, y\rangle \in H \iff M^{(j)}_{T,y} \in L$.

Indeed, if $\langle T, y\rangle \in H$ then $M^{(j)}_{T,y}$ halts on input $x = \varepsilon$. Moreover, the number of steps executed is at least $j$, and $|x| = 0 < i$. This shows that $M^{(j)}_{T,y} \in T$.
On the other hand, $\langle T, y\rangle \not\in H$ implies that the simulation perfomred by $M^{(j)}_{T,y}$ does not halt, and hence $M^{(j)}_{T,y} \not\in L$.

Since $H$ is a well-known undecidable language, so is $L$.